# Community detection on a very large graph

Tags: social-networking, bigdata

I have a very large directed graph (a social network graph) with about 8 million nodes. I would like to run a community detection algorithm on the same (it can be overlapping or non-overlapping).

I have had a look at InfoMap but it is too slow for the size of such a graph - it might as well take weeks (i think). BIGCLAM is another implementation in Stanford SNAP but it is only for undirected graphs.

I have a server at my disposal with 40 cores and 128GB RAM (And my network on the disk is around 60GBs) which I can leverage. Does there exist any implementation or research that could help me?

Answer (score 1):

Louvain Method is fast! There is an implementation: https://github.com/vtraag/louvain-igraph.

You are supposed to install graph library and numpy library first.

Answer (score 0):

If you possible, Install R programming language

and then, install igraph library

there are many community detection algorithms,

Infomap is good but it is really slow.

I think louvain algorithm is suitable to your situation. Louvain algorithm is wonderfully!!! fast

please try it!