# Community detection for large, directed graphs

Tags: graph, cluster-analysis, igraph, directed-graph

In [Clustering and Community Detection in Directed Networks:A Survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0971) Malliaros & Vazirgiannis (2013) describe many algorithms for clustering and community detection in directed graphs. I have a relatively large graph, 400.000 nodes, 180.000.000 edges and are looking for software that could detect communities in it, but the program for network analysis I've looked into, the [igraph](https://igraph.org) package for R, does not seem to have any algorithms that is capable of detecting clusters in big directed networks (`igraph` has `cluster_fast_greedy()`, and `cluster_louvain()` but they only work on undirected graphs). Is there any package, either in R or in python, that can do this?

A similar question was posed in [Community detection on a very large graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094401/community-detection-on-a-very-large-graph), the difference being that I need packages for python or R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Leiden algorithm from the Python package [`leidenalg`](https://leidenalg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which should be even faster than the Louvain algorithm that you mention. This package works on a multitude of different networks, including directed networks, but also multiplex networks and networks with negative links. In addition, it supports a range of different quality functions. It should easily scale to networks with millions of node (provided it fits in memory of course), with runtimes usually of a couple of minutes at most.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the package (and a number of related publications).

Comment: I have used your package and found it to be fast, scaleable and bug free.

Comment: Good to hear, thank you! If you do come across any problems, feel free to open an issue in GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for developing leidenalg which worked great on my dataset.